# AOP works only with @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop, autowired, spring-aop

I have the following spring controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {
    UserService user = new UserService();

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String goFirstPage(){
        user.showUserName(new User("Mike"));
        return"firstpage";
    }

}
```

and the following aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class UserAspect {


    @Before("execution(public void com.project.aopmaven.services.UserService.showUserName(..))")
    public void logUser(){
        System.out.println("Logging User");
    }

}
```

It doesn't work, "Logging User" message is not shown (even the UserService object is instantiated in the controller class). But, when we add the `@Autowired` annotation to the UserService defined in the controller it works!

```
@Autowired
UserService user = new UserService();
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring AOP allows using AOP on Spring beans, not on random objects. And it's based on proxies: instead of injecting the actual implementation of the bean, Spring injects a proxy that wraps the actual implementation, and invokes the aspects before/after invoking the wrapped bean implementation.

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying)

Comment: Let me explain a little more: What JB means is that if you directly call the `UserService` constructor, you are not using Spring in order to create your component (and its dynamic proxy, if necessary). Auto-injection does delegate object creation to Spring, though. You could also use something like `myApplicationContext.getBean(UserService.class)` if you insist on creating the object inside your method instead of getting it injected by Spring. But the whole point of using a dependency injection container like Spring is - well, dependency injection. ;-)

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot guys.